# How can I fix this problem duplicate entry for key parent_guardian.UK_nk6368kpl2m2lvwouue8t4mj

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a form that saves that into different tables. The main problem is after saving the first data, i am unable to save second or third data. Each time I try to save another data I get this problem which has something to do with dupllicate entry key. I don't know how to fix this and I need some help

Below is the code sample

Student entity

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Student extends IdBaseEntity{

    @Column(name = "admission_number")
    Long admissionNumber;
    
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    String firstName;
    
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    String lastName;
    
    @Column(name = "other_name")
    String otherName;

    @Column(name = "date_of_birth")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    Date dob;
    
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "student", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    ParentGuardian parentGuardian;   
    @Transient
    public String getDobOnForm() {
        DateFormat dateFomatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        return dateFomatter.format(this.dob);
    }
    
    public void setDobOnForm(String dateString) {
        DateFormat dateformatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        try {
            this.dob = dateformatter.parse(dateString);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

parentGuardian entity

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent_guardian")
public class ParentGuardian extends IdBaseEntity{
    
    @Column(name = "father_name")
    String fatherName;
    
    @Column(name = "father_occupation")
    String fatherOccupation;
    
    @Column(name = "father_phone_number")
    String fatherPhoneNumber;
    
    @Column(name = "mother_name")
    String motherName;

    @Column(name = "mother_occupation")
    String motherOccupation;
    
    @Column(name = "mother_phone_number")
    String motherPhoneNumber;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    Student student;
}
```

thymeleaf form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
    layout:decorate="~{../fragments/main_layout}">
<head th:insert="../fragments/main_layout :: page_head('staffs','none')">

</head>
<body>
<div layout:fragment="content" class="main-container">
    <div class="card cardspace">
    <form th:action="@{/students/save}" th:object="${studentParentGuardianDto}" method="post"
    onsubmit="return checkStudentEmailUniqueness(this);">
        <div class="shadow p-3 mb-4 bg-body rounded">
            <div  class="bg-secondary">
                <span class="fs-5 fw-5">Student Admission</span>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary ">Import Student</button>
            </div>
            <div class="card card-body ">
                <div class="row ">              
                    <div class="form-group col">
                        <label class="col-form-label">Admission Number</label>                      
                            <input type="text"  class="form-control"
                                required="required">
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col">
                        <label class="col-form-label">First Name</label>
                        <div class="">
                            <input type="text"  class="form-control"
                                th:field="*{firstName}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col">
                        <label class="col-form-label">Other Name</label>
                        <div class="">
                            <input type="text"  class="form-control"
                                th:field="*{otherName}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col">
                        <label class="col-form-label">Last Name</label>
                        <div class="">
                            <input type="text"  class="form-control"
                                th:field="*{lastName}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col">
                        <label class="col-form-label">Date of Birth</label>
                        <div class="">
                            <input type="date"  class="form-control"
                                th:field="*{getDobOnForm}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>          
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="shadow p-3 mb-4 bg-body rounded">
            <div  class="bg-secondary">
                <span class="fs-5 fw-5">Parent Guardian Detail</span>               
            </div>
            <div class="card card-body ">
                <div class="row ">
                    <div class="form-group col">
                        <label class="col-form-label">Father Name</label>
                            <input type="text"  class="form-control"
                                th:field="*{fatherName}">                   
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group col">
                        <label class="col-form-label">Father Phone</label>
                        <div class="">
                            <input type="text"  class="form-control"
                                th:field="*{fatherPhoneNumber}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col">
                        <label class="col-form-label">Father Occupation</label>
                        <div class="">
                            <input type="text"  class="form-control"
                                th:field="*{fatherOccupation}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="row ">
                    <div class="form-group col">
                        <label class="col-form-label">Mother Name</label>
                        <div class="">
                            <input type="text"  class="form-control"
                                th:field="*{motherName}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col">
                        <label class="col-form-label">Mother Phone</label>
                        <div class="">
                            <input type="text"  class="form-control"
                                th:field="*{motherPhoneNumber}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col">
                        <label class="col-form-label">Mother Occupation</label>
                        <div class="">
                            <input type="text"  class="form-control"
                                th:field="*{motherOccupation}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="row ">
                    <div class="form-group col">
                        <label class="col-form-label me-3">If Guardian is </label>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input type="radio"  class="form-check-input fatherRadio"
                                value="Father" th:field="*{isGuardianFatherMotherOther}">
                            <label class="form-check-label">Father</label>  
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input type="radio"  class="form-check-input motherRadio"
                                value="Mother" th:field="*{isGuardianFatherMotherOther}">
                            <label class="form-check-label">Mother</label>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">SAVE</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div th:replace="fragments :: modal_dialog"></div>
    </div>
    <script th:src="@{/js/common_modal.js}"></script>
    <script>
    
    contextPath = "[[@{/}]]";
    
        //code to make COD button visible when radio button is checked
        $(document).ready(function() {
        
            $(".fatherRadio").on("click", function(){
                //removes the css class d-none to make the button visible
                $(".forRadio").addClass("d-none");
            });
            $(".motherRadio").on("click", function(){
                //removes the css class d-none to make the button visible
                $(".forRadio").addClass("d-none");
            });         
        });
    </script>   
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

handler method that display student form

```
    @GetMapping("/students/new")
    public String showStudentForm(@ModelAttribute("student") Student student,
             Model model) {

        return "students/student_admission";
    }
```

handler method that save students

```
    
    @PostMapping("/students/save")
    public String saveStudent(@ModelAttribute("student") Student student){
        
        ParentGuardian parentGuardian = student.getParentGuardian();
        
        parentGuardian.setStudent(student);
        
        studentService.saveStudent(student);
        
        parentGuardianService.saveParentGuardian(parentGuardian);
        
        
        return "redirect:/students/new";
    }
```

The error message I get when i try to insert another record

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '' for key 'parent_guardian.UK_nk6368kpl2m2lvwouue8t4mj'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:916) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1061) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1009) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1320) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:994) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3342) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3980) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:653) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:283) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:322) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:340) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:184) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:779) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:727) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$7.cascade(CascadingActions.java:301) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$7.cascade(CascadingActions.java:291) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:513) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:434) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:474) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:298) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:184) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:53) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:737) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:721) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:360) ~[spring-orm-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at jdk.proxy13/jdk.proxy13.$Proxy245.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at jdk.proxy13/jdk.proxy13.$Proxy245.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:613) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:288) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:516) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:628) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:168) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:77) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:390) ~[spring-tx-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:163) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:218) ~[spring-aop-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at jdk.proxy13/jdk.proxy13.$Proxy254.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.sch.admin.student.StudentService.saveStudent(StudentService.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.sch.admin.student.StudentController.saveStudent(StudentController.java:186) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:6.0]
    at
```

[picture of the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYeI8.png)

Comment: Which fields does the UK_nk6368kpl2m2lvwouue8t4mj contraint include?

Comment: @times29 I am able to fix it. The problem was not the code but a constraints I placed on one of the fields in the Parent Guardian entitity. Thank you.